# UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization Even if I select allow, RequestAuthorization in Xamarin Forms iOS returns false

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm working on adding notification support to an iOS (Xamarin Forms) project.
I'm going to ask users for permission to allow notifications in app delegate.

[image]

When I run the application, a message will appear asking for permission. It was given approvalGanted as false after you clicked the "Allow" button in the code.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .